# How to clip a range of colors into a predefined color set? (any language)

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, colors

I have some color list as a result of some image extracting. And i want to clip those colors into some predefined colors.

---

Let's say input includes some dark and light colors of **red**. They all count as red. 
  Or if some color has excess saturation levels it becomes gray, black or white in that regard.

---

First solution i think of was to transfer those colors to HSL so i can make some switch statement just by reading the Hue, and then mapping them would be easy. But then it is to hard to eyeball values when there are also lightness and saturation values. In the end i could not manage to get good result from these technique.

---

So my question is "Is there any definite way to convert those different colors to specific color set?"

Comment: Yes, of course there's a *definite way* - you just need to define the parameters and write the code

Comment: Perhaps calculating the [distance between colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113979/calculate-distance-between-colors-in-hsv-space) would help