# Detect original color regardless of light/scanning conditions

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have the following color palette, which consists of eight RGB colors that are quite distinct from one another:

```
color_palette = [
    (255, 255, 255), # White
    (0, 0, 0), # Black
    (0, 255, 255), # Cyan
    (255, 0, 255), # Magenta
    (255, 255, 0), # Yellow
    (0, 0, 255), # Blue
    (255, 0, 0), # Red
    (0, 255, 0) # Green
]
```

What I am interested in doing is print a bunch of pixels with those colors on a piece of paper and then scan the paper back and be able to compute the closest match of each color to a color from the palette regardless of scanning/light conditions or if the colors have faded. (due to ink exposed to light over time)

I came across color spaces such as Lab but they seem to be aiming at human perception, not scanning.

Is there a color space/method that works well especially for computing this?

Comment: Just get the BGR color distance between original and scanned for each color and find the smallest distance. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference

Comment: Right now I am calculating the RGB euclidean distance but my thought was that this does not take into account light/fading properly.

Comment: Is the lighting and fading such that one color changes so much so as to be closer to some other color. If not, then it should be OK. You said your color table has colors that are far apart.

Comment: You could convert to linear color rather than non-linear (sRGB or similar) and do the Euclidean distance in linear color. Perhaps that might be better???

Comment: so you're trying to characterize the transfer function that goes through printing, physical fading, and scanning? please describe the complexity of this that you realize. I'm not sure you fully grasp the scope and intricacies. this will require a bunch of research.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping that this would have been solved already at an academic level, if not then this is indeed beyond the scope of a project.

Comment: You might be able to just match hues. That might avoid the affects of lighting and scanning.

Comment: Perhaps this might help.  https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2018/4652526/.  For hue distance see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113979/calculate-distance-between-colors-in-hsv-space

Comment: Use a reference objecf in the image from which you perfectly know the real colors. Otherwise you wont be able to correct the light color of the scene unless you enforce to use a well known light source.

Comment: "reference objects" would be color cards, or a palette printed in a corner of your fading printout. that should present each pigment individually but also in combination. the fading might be sensitive to concentration of pigments, so you'll want to present (stepped) gradients too. while you're at it, make sure this thing is easy to locate. look into Optical Mark Recognition. circles are easy to locate. place some of those around the array of color patches.